# How to make column out of several rows?

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape

I'm pretty new to R and programming itself,and right now I have an issue with my data.frame that is not allowing me to continue my work.

I have a set of data as follows

### Table 1

```
    Individual             Score
    Tim                      45
    Tim                      77
    Tim                      32
    Clare                    92
    Clare                    70
    Clare                    88
```

Let me explain the table 1 above, I have several individuals (TIm and Clare in the example above) and I have their score in a test they presented in 3 different occasions (2009, 2010, 2011) I am trying to figure out a way to turn that above into something like this:

### Table2

```
    Individual             Score09             Score10             Score11
    Tim                      45                   77                  32
    Clare                    92                   70                  88
```

I used ddply to obtain the Table 1, since I originally had the information of the subsets of the test (the variable score is just the sum of all the subset)

Please let me know if there a way to actually end up with Table 2 instead of Table 1, Since I have over 10000 observations and the Table 1 set up wont let me move forward with the intended propose.

### EDIT:

The original df from where Table 1 was generated is:

The data frame is as follows

```
    Base          Individual     score_math    score_bio     score_chem
    SB1120091       Tim              12            23             10
    SB1120092       Tim              30            25             22
    SB1120101       Tim              17             5             10
    SB1120091       Clare            50            20             22
    SB1120092       Clare            40            10             20
    SB1120101       Clare            47            20             21
```

And the code was:

`>Table1 <-ddply(x, .(Indivual), summarise, Score=(score_math*score_bio*score_chem))`

### EDIT2:

The original data set has no Year variable but a base variable that provides information about when the test was taken.

Also The Score variable is calculated with as a product of all the subsets scores.

Comment: What's your code for getting Table 1?

Comment: @Aaron The code for Table 1 was

`> Table1 <- ddply(x, .(Individual), summarise, Score=(score_math+score_bio+score_chem)`

Comment: See my comments on the answer below.

Comment: Rather than modifying Table 1, as the answers so far do, it seems a better choice to just get Table 2 directly.  I thought your code from Table 1 would be enough to see how to do that but it's still not clear.  what does your `x` data frame look like?

Comment: Aha, you already have year in the data set!  This will greatly simplify all the other solutions!  In the future, a reproducible example would be very helpful to start with (and one of us probably should have asked for it first -- sorry!)

Comment: @Aaron I edited the question with the original df

Comment: Instead of copying/pasting the original data frame, run `dput(x)` and paste the output instead; this will allow others to quickly input your data frame into their R sessions.

Comment: @Aaron This set was a dummy-set, I tried to keep it as simple for me given my lack of expertise in the field, but It didn't work... I don't have year variable as "year", I have a code that includes letters and numbers that refer to a specific semester when the test was taken (SB1120111, refers to the first semester of 2011 in whitch the SB11 test was taken)... Also the Total Score is calculated by a cobb-douglas function that is subject to changes.

Comment: OK... so will one of the solutions given work for you? Or is there still something needed?  If one of the solutions works, please mark it with a check so others know that's what worked for you.  Also, please click the up-arrow by any of the solutions that were helpful.  Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I have marked the answerrs that have been helpful, but I haven't been able to solve the issue...

Comment: @MJAS: It's not clear to me where you're still stuck.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @Aaron I am still stuck but I'm trying a different approach to see if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data:

```
df <- structure(list(Individual = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                     .Label = c("Clare", "Tim"), class = "factor"), 
                     Score = c(45, 77, 32, 92, 70, 88), 
                     count = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), 
                     .Names = c("Individual", "Score", "count"), 
                     row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
df$count <- rep(c("09", "10", "11"), 2)
```

- Using `reshape` from base stat:

  ```
  > reshape(df, idvar="Individual", timevar="count", direction="wide", sep="")

  #   Individual Score09 Score10 Score11
  # 1        Tim      45      77      32
  # 4      Clare      92      70      88
  ```

Comment: +1 instead of `count`, why not make a year variable? It's a simple `transform` statement to the original data: `df<-transform(df, timevar=ave(Score, Individual, FUN=function(x) 8 + seq(x)))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `reshape2` package:

```
# presuming your data frame is 'xx'
library(reshape2)

# Create a 'Case' Column
xx$Case <- rep(paste0("Score", c("09", "10", "11")), 2)

dcast(xx, Individual ~ Case, value.var="Score")
 Individual Score09 Score10 Score11
      Clare      92      70      88
        Tim      45      77      32
```

Answer (score 2):

Now that you have provided your original table, use `xtabs()` on the original dataset. Assuming your dataset is named "x":

```
xtabs(score_math + score_bio + score_chem ~ Individual + Year, x)
#           Year
# Individual 2009 2010 2011
#      Clare   92   70   88
#      Tim     45   77   32
```

Comment: Excellent -- I always forget that xtabs can sum.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ddply` call is splitting the function by Individual, which results in a separate data frame for each individual, and computing the sum on each data frame separately.  There are multiple rows for each individual in the data set, so this sum has one sum for each row.  It then combines the data back together, and by default, gives one row in the result for each initial row.  But you want one row for each individual; if we just transpose the result, it makes it into a matrix with one row, which results in the desired behavior.

Using the data you provided:

```
x <- read.table(text="Year Individual score_math score_bio score_chem
2009 Tim 12 23 10
2010 Tim 30 25 22
2011 Tim 17 5 10
2009 Clare 50 20 22
2010 Clare 40 10 20
2011 Clare 47 20 21", header=TRUE)
```

Here's a revised `ddply` call:

```
> ddply(x, .(Individual), summarise, Score=t((score_math+score_bio+score_chem)))
  Individual Score.1 Score.2 Score.3
1      Clare      92      70      88
2        Tim      45      77      32
```

`ddply` is really not quite the right tool, though; you're just doing a very simple calculation on each row and then reshaping.  My preference would be to add a column for the total score, and then use `dcast` from the `reshape2` package.  One reason for this preference is to so that you would have a complete master data set with all the information you might want later, and then use that to do all computations and transformations.

```
library(reshape2)
x$Total <- with(x, score_math + score_bio + score_chem)
dcast(x, Individual ~ Year, value.var="Total")
```